# Enabling audible terminal bell/beep on wheezy

Tags: raspbian, hardware, audio, lxde, modules

I am trying to enable an audible terminal bell/beep through the 1/8" mini-rca audio out (headphone jack) on debian wheezy with the rapsberry pi model b.  Normal audio works as expected, when playing a shockwave file in Midori with gnash for example.

I turned the **Audible bell** setting in **LXTerminal** preferences **ON**, and tried the following:

`$ xkbbell` (no sound)

`$ xkbbell -dev 0` (X Error of failed request: 146)

`$ beep` and `$ beep -f 500 -l 700` after installing it with apt (no sound)

That said, this is all in an attempt to hear the bell sound triggered by **PuTTY**, when **Action to happen when a bell occurs** is set to **Make default system alert sound**.  There is no option, like in the Windows version of PuTTY, to play a custom sound file when a bell occurs.

I've read that running `# modprobe snd_hda_intel` on other linux machines can redirect sound output intended for the PC speaker (which the raspberry lacks) to ALSA.  Running that command tells me that this module is not found.  I don't know how to acquire it with apt.

I'm really hoping someone has some insight...I'm dizzy from Googling!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to hear the bell emitted from the Raspberry Pi on it's own, or when you SSH into it?

Comment: I want to hear the bell emitted from the Raspberry Pi on it's own. I thought that might be confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the desired results using a program called **softbeep**.

http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/softbeep/softbeep-0.3.tar.gz

I needed to obtain the **libncurses5** and **libX11** development packages to compile it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libX11-dev
```

After compiling (`make`), I needed to edit the `sb-beep` file to (1) point to an available sound file on the pi and (2) play the sound with `aplay` as opposed to `esdplay` before installing (`make install`).

Worked like a charm! Thank you Lennart Poettering (softbeep author).

Answer (score 5):

I found that you  could load the sound drivers and stuff on Raspbian with:

```
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835 && sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
```

The first command loads the sound driver module, the second I think sets the sound output to the 3.5mm socket.

You can then use `alsamixer` to adjust the volume, and `speaker-test -c2 -t sine` to test the speakers

You can also use the `speaker-test` util to produce different sounds, using `-c1` for mono, `c2` to switch between each channel of stereo, and `-f` to do different frequencies of noise - `speaker-test --help` gives alot more options:

```
speaker-test 1.0.25

Usage: speaker-test [OPTION]... 
-h,--help   help
-D,--device playback device
-r,--rate   stream rate in Hz
-c,--channels   count of channels in stream
-f,--frequency  sine wave frequency in Hz
-F,--format sample format
-b,--buffer ring buffer size in us
-p,--period period size in us
-P,--nperiods   number of periods
-t,--test   pink=use pink noise, sine=use sine wave, wav=WAV file
-l,--nloops specify number of loops to test, 0 = infinite
-s,--speaker    single speaker test. Values 1=Left, 2=right, etc
-w,--wavfile    Use the given WAV file as a test sound
-W,--wavdir Specify the directory containing WAV files

Recognized sample formats are: S8 S16_LE S16_BE FLOAT_LE S32_LE S32_BE
```

So to generate a 2 second beep, this worked fine:

```
speaker-test -c1 -t sine -f 800 -P 2 -p 0.4 -l 1
```

For a better beep, I generated a 0.25 second beep file in Audacity *(Created new audio track, generated 440 Hz tone, amplified it by 11)*, then copied it onto my Pi - I could then play it with `aplay beep.wav`. This I then copied to `~/.local`, and created this bash script at `~/.local/bin/beep` (I ran `mkdir ~/.local/bin` first):

```
#!/bin/bash
aplay -q $HOME/.local/beep.wav
exit
```

I then created these lines in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

and then I ran the following

```
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/beep
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and then I could simply run `beep` to make a beep noise

Comment: +1 for the paste and go code sample for a 2 seconds beep with speaker-test `speaker-test -c1 -t sine -f 800 -P 2 -p 0.4 -l 1`

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to make a shorter sound using:

```
( speaker-test -t sine -c 2 -s 2 -f 800 & TASK_PID=$! ; sleep 0.09 ; kill -s SIGKILL $TASK_PID ) > /dev/null
```

This sends a signal after 0.09 s (but longer due to overhead) to stop. The shortest time that gave a sound on my system (Raspbian Stretch on Raspberry Pi 3) was 0.06 s. I redirect all output to /dev/null so it looks like a normal command. See `man speaker-test` for explanation of the options.