# Auto-execute desktop shortcut problem

Tags: desktop, raspberry-pi-desktop

I have created file `/home/pi/Desktop/DecoderPro.desktop` with the contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=DecoderPro
Comment=JMRI DecoderPro
Icon=/home/pi/JMRI/resources/dp3_48x48.gif
Exec=/home/pi/JMRI/DecoderPro
Terminal=false;
```

Each time I click the icon on the desktop I get the message:

```
This text file 'DecoderPro' seems to be an executable script. what do you want to do with it "desktop entry"?
```

Is it possible to make this desktop shortcut to start automatically, without the message?

EDIT: It seems that `/home/pi/JMRI/DecoderPro` is the source of the problem.  It is also script starting with `#! /bin/bash`.  But it is also +x.

Currently I have `buster 10` version and if I remember right, in previous version of Raspbian this worked.

Comment: Did you try to make it executable? `chmod +x ~/Desktop/DecoderPro.desktop`

Comment: Yes.  Didn't help.

Comment: @jake Maybe this will help. `/home/pi/JMRI/DecoderPro` is also a script that starts with `#! /bin/bash`.  It is also +x.

Comment: @Pygmalion, And if the problem came from the line: `Comment = JMRI DecoderPro`, DecoderPro is also after this space ... try:`Comment = "JMRI DecoderPro"`maybe?

Comment: @Ephemeral No, it didn't help.

Comment: @Pygmalion, I see that [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_entries) : `# The path to the folder in which the executable is run
Path=/home/pi/JMRI

# The executable of the application, possibly with arguments.
Exec=bash DecoderPro
` but I think you must call a binary not a shell script or `bash DecoderPro` is probably correct ... I'm looking for that.

Comment: @Ephemeral `Exec=bash DecoderPro` didn't help.  What is even more mysterious is that I think that in previous version of raspbian this worked.

Comment: @Pygmalion, ok I have remove my answer. I don't known. sorry.

Comment: @Ephemeral But this worked on your raspberry, for a script without .sh as an extension?

Comment: @Pygmalion, yes. My script for my test name is `Voltage` with just vcgen command , also i have no bash header but It 's on my older raspberry with jessie... have you try with `Path` ? [here some related](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191854)

Comment: @Ephemeral I have `buster 10`, freshly installed few days ago, because SD card drop dead.  Yes, I used `Path` command.

Comment: For other noobs like me, found the solution https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=248380#p1516491

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a file `/home/pi/Desktop/test.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Name=test
Comment=The official
Icon=emblem-debian
Type=Application
Path=/home/pi
Exec=bash test
Terminal=true
```

bash script named `test` (UTF-8) in `/home/pi` dir:

```
echo hello world
read
```

adjust permissions:

```
chmod u+x /home/pi/test
```

Then open:
`~$ pcmanfm`
go to
`Edit/Preferences/General`, Check box for "`Don't ask options on launch executable file`" [ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333256/how-to-skip-execute-file-dialog-in-lubuntu-pcmanfm)

Edit: `Terminal` must be `true` if you want to see the output of your script.

Tested on fresh Raspbian Buster install.

Comment: OK, this works for me.  It is not on the desktop screen though...

Comment: @Pygmalion, yes no icon on desktop. I would read more about this later and update my answer if needed. You have 3 tools starting with `desktop-file-edit` , `desktop-file-verify` and `desktop-file-install` , when I use edit tool, nothing is done.

Comment: Actually when I used `desktop-file-install`, there was error because of using semicolon.  It seems that semicolon after `Terminal=false` is also a problem.  Original question is about icon on the desktop screen, so I would appreciate if you find the solution in that way.

Comment: @Pygmalion, Yes indeed my answer is not really correct but it is an approach that works and that will surely help me to understand the future. I am currently looking for the desktop.

Comment: @Pygmalion, it's ok after some hours , it's just a checkbox to uncheck, ho !

Comment: For me it works even with my original script, no `Path`, no `bash`.  Just `pcmanfm` is necessary.

Comment: @Pygmalion, You need terminal = true if you use an echo in the bash script else , no terminal is open and then nothing is displayed but yes `Terminal can be false` for 'background commands'.  You have right for Exec work with `Exec=/home/pi/test`, the `test` require execution (
I had it removed) right else you have an Error : Invalid Desktop Entry file.

Answer (score 0):

thank for helping me out, you are my savior. I did follow your step

1. Hit the terminal icon, then it will appear some thing like this "user@rasperipy: ~$"
2. type in the command "pcmanfm" + enter
3. There will be a window show up, n you guys follow his guide (go to Edit/Preferences/General, Check box for "Don't ask options on launch executable file)
4. It should have a check box there which is empty, n you need to checked it

Excuse my typo <3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).