# WiFi/BT link on desktop as icon

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

I'm setting up a Pi4 to land on a blank page and have streaming services like Netflix as large icons and they run in kiosk mode.  So I've hidden the bar across the top.  What I would like to do is to have an icon on the desktop that links to wifi and bluetooth or both in one.  I like the simplicity of the Wifi/BT setup from the bar at the top, but I'm hiding the bar and want it as a large app icon or link.  What is the best way of either linking to the gui that pops up when you set up wifi or using a completely different one instead?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> For Wi-Fi you can use `wpa_cli` tools (or with only `wpa_supplicant`
> and `dhclient` tools you can connect to Wi-Fi AP and get an IP
> address). The `bluetoothctl` tool can be used for Bluetooth
> connection.

**One solution is :**

You can create [Desktop shorcut](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100679/auto-execute-desktop-shortcut-problem/100696#100696) with `.desktop` file.

You can create your own connection scripts and use it in the `.desktop` file.

**Another option is : (Edit 03/05/2022)**

Install `blueman` [package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/blueman) :

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Create desktop shortcut for bluetooth app:

```
nano /home/pi/Desktop/bluetooth.desktop
```

File content :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Name=bluetooth
Comment=bluetooth
Icon=preferences-system-bluetooth
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=blueman
```

Install `nm-tray` [package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nm-tray&searchon=names&suite=bullseye&section=all):

```
sudo apt-get install nm-tray
```

Create desktop shortcut for wifi/ethernet app:

```
nano /home/pi/Desktop/network.desktop
```

File content :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Name=network
Comment=network
Icon=network-wireless-connected-100
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=nmtui
```

I think it would be better to disable the following lxpanel plugins from lxpanel menu or remove them entirely: `lxplug-bluetooth` and `lxplug-network`, for example:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge lxplug-bluetooth... lxplug-network...`

- You can also change `Icon=` if you remove plugins:

`Icon=preferences-system-bluetooth` (use default lxplug-bluetooth plugin icon) → `Icon=blueman`

`Icon=network-wireless-connected-100` (use default lxplug-network plugin icon) → `Icon=network-wired` (use default nm-tray ethernet icon)

**Note**: `nmtui` is a console GUI app.

Comment: I'm working on that, (currently fried my pi, so awaiting new one). When I looked at those commands, they are terminal commands, I wanted to give an easier GUI interface to connect to.  But I will try this first to see what it looks like.

Comment: @styleruk, You can see my edited answer for more appropriate answer.

Comment: @styleruk, Another answer update at 03/05/2022, use `nm-tray` instead of `wicd`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions here. I have made both desktop entries and the bluetooth one gives an error 'invalid desktop entry file; '/home/pi/Desktop/bluetooth.desktop'

Comment: the wifi desktop file gives error 'Failed to execute child process "xterm" (No such file or directory)

Comment: @styleruk, What is your OS ? (My test is on `Debian bullseye`)

Comment: I'm on Debian buster at the moment.

Comment: I found using network manager confused the Pi, I'm guessing I did not disable the plugins correctly and this lead to wifi not working.  So I have stuck to using just the panel options that come with raspbian and hiding a reduced sized menu ribbon at the top corner.  This looks fairly neat for the prototype level I'm working at.