# Shutdown safely raspberry pi without keyboard and network

Tags: headless, shutdown

A friend lent me a little used **RPi 4B** to try it before to buy it. I am not sure to buy it but for now I simply connected a display and powered it.

By bad luck I noticed that my only monitor that handles HDMI no longer works, so I can not see what the device is displaying.

I found with [nmap](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#nmap-command) that the RPi could be accessed by SSH. I attempted to login to it with the [default credentials](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-default-login-password/) for user **pi** but these does not work. So I asked to my friend the working credentials which do not work anymore.

So I plugged in a USB keyboard, its LEDs indicated that it was operational and I tried [the Magic SysRq Key](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59529/shutting-down-the-pi-safely-without-ssh-or-a-monitor/59539#59539) REISUO combination but I must have made a mistake or the combination is not exactly the same on a AZERTY keyboard (I'm French) because now not only the device has not turned off but the keyboard LEDs are no longer lit. Even when changing ports nothing happens.

I saw an ultimate proposition which indicates [to unplug the power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59529/shutting-down-the-pi-safely-without-ssh-or-a-monitor/59530#59530) (as my ACT LED is not lit and is not blinking) which can work ... or not !

As the device not belong to me, I wish to know if someone have a newer or a better solution to shut down safely without risking corrupting the system ?

Comment: Just pull the power, you'll get away with it more often than not. Or try a different HDMI cable connected to a different TV. Raspberry Pi 4Bs won't work at 1366x768 (without some tweaks to config.txt).

Comment: Thank you ! Pulling the power connector is what I finally made because I had no choice. As I do not own a device with a working HDMI port I could not try it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally forced the switched off the device with the upstream button after having verify that the ACT LED was not lit and was not blinking (as proposed in [this thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59529/shutting-down-the-pi-safely-without-ssh-or-a-monitor/59530#59530)).

For those who can be interrested I detailed all my work on [this thread](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1991945#p1991945).

Thank you, problem solved !