# I don't get a system bell in LXTerminal on Raspberry Pi 4b / Raspbian

Tags: lxde, lxterminal

I don't get the customary system "bell" at the command prompt when I type ctl-g or when editing a file with vim. I do get sound when playing an audio file (through HDMI to my monitor).

As I was typing this question this "Similar question" popped up ([Enabling audible terminal bell/beep on wheezy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8927/enabling-audible-terminal-bell-beep-on-wheezy))

I am running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on Pi 4b
Is this still the preferred solution?

Thank you.

Comment: `Is this still the preferred solution?` Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: I have downloaded and compiled the softbeep suggestion. I have not yet provided the required SB_RUN program to actually make the raspberry pi to beep. Interestingly the provided test program does "beep" when executed from a ssh session - presumably sends a ctl-g back.

Comment: I had to add `typedef struct FILE _IO_FILE;` to libsoftbeep.c in order to compile in Raspbian Buster. `softbeep` works, but it ignores "Audible bell" in LXTerminal and "Beep when there is an error for keyboard input" in Mouse and Keyboard Settings, i.e. if you use `softbeep` the bell sound if these boxed are checked or not. In Bash `printf "\a\a"` doesn't work, but it works in perlconsole.